# Please Help! !Unconfirmed transfer for over 12 hours using recommended fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I have been waiting for over 12 hours for this transaction to confirm:
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/76621daadefc4b5756e23ada1358ca4544683a6af0edda1766b1713ed9224188?show_adv=true
it is unfortunately pretty important. I am using multibit and using the recommended fee, perhaps I need to update. Will mulit bit keep resending the transaction or should it cancel at some point?

Comment: If anyone can help me get this confirmed I would really appreciate it..

Comment: It went through, i'll put a bigger fee next time to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

It is confirmed now.

The fee for that transaction should be little more than 0.0001 btc.

Click "Settings" in Multibit and increase the fee to about 100 satoshi per byte to get fast confirmations.